# My HTC Trophy has no internet connection unless connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: cellular-data, 7.5

My HTC Trophy is only able to connect to the internet if I am connected to Wi-Fi.  Otherwise, I get "You might have lost your cellular data connection".  This just started happening a few days ago and I am finally done waiting it out to see if it will fix itself.

I called Verizon technical support who walked me through the following steps:

- Go to Settings > system > cellular, turn off data connection, and turn it back on
- In the same screen, set mode to CDMA
- Clear IE cookies/history
- Dial *288 and go to option 1 to activate

His final step was to do a factory reset.  However, because there is no way to back up my SMS messages on my WP7.5 in the year 2013, I am not doing that because I need those texts.

**Edit:** HaLaBi suggests I add APN settings.  Here are the fields available on my phone:

APN
User name
Password
Proxy server/URL
Proxy port

I don't see any other fields.

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: @HaLaBi I forgot to add that as one of the things I did indeed try.  I've restarted it cold several times over the past few days.

Comment: Ok, one thing is left to try, delete the APN and add a new one then select it as the active APN.

Comment: @HaLaBi Any quick links you can point me to on how to do this?  I see the Add APN option, but I don't know any of this stuff.  I have Verizon 3G.

Comment: Check the settings for Verizon here: http://theunlockr.com/internet-mms-settings/

Comment: @HaLaBi I came across that and tried it, but no luck.  It seems that the fields are different.  I'll update my question with all the fields.

Comment: just fill the APN field and try.

Comment: @HaLaBi I answered my own question with a solution.  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several days ago while trying to fix another issue with my phone (my data connection was working fine at the time), I downloaded Connection Setup from the Marketplace.  It wasn't doing what I thought it would do, so I uninstalled it.  I *think* that's around the time when the connection issue began.  I reinstalled the app just now.  It didn't work at first, but, after opening it several more times, it was finally able to restore my data connection.

I am wondering if this app actually broke my connection before, taking vital settings along with it when it was uninstalled.  I hate to think that I have to have this app on my phone from now on like some kind of life support, but I am getting a new phone soon, so it's not the end of the world.